# Integration: "partial" Beta function?

Tags: integration, beta-function

It is well known that the Beta function is defined as

$$B(x,y) =\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{t^{x-1}}{{(1+t)}^{x+y}}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

What if I have the exact same integral but with a non-zero lower bound, i.e.

$$\int\limits_a^\infty \frac{t^{x-1}}{{(1+t)}^{x+y}}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

where a>0. Can this integral be expressed in terms of Special functions (Beta, Hypergeometric, etc.)?

Thanks

Comment: See [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) for some references on the incomplete beta function.

Comment: I see - the incomplete beta function might be useful. It could at least be possible to use $$\int\limits_0^\infty f(x) ~dx = \int\limits_0^a f(x) ~dx + \int\limits_a^\infty f(x) ~dx$$ to derive some difference of a beta function and an incomplete beta function.

Comment: I think this has a cleaner expression in terms of $\,_2F_1$ than incomplete beta, but don't have it quite pinned down yet.

Answer (score 2):

Things turn out a bit nicer if we use a fixed lower limit rather than a fixed upper limit. We have
$$
\int_0^a\frac{t^{x-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}}dt = a^x \int_0^1 u^{x-1}(1+a u)^{-x-y}du = a^xB(1,x)\,_2F_1\left({x+y,\,x\atop x+1};-a\right),
$$
found from [this form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type) of the hypergeometric integral. Since $B(1,x) = 1/x$, we have for the original integral
$$
\int_a^\infty\frac{t^{x-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}}dt =B(x,y) - \frac{a^x}{x}\,_2F_1\left({x+y,\,x\atop x+1};-a\right).
$$